# how to make thread wait until another thread has completed that method execution

Tags: java, spring, jpa, concurrency

Although this question seems basic, my scenario is quite different from other posts @stackoverflow.  I am using spring with JPA & jersey(REST) implementation. Whenever I hit 2 requests concurrently from curl to my Java REST method in order to update database resources, first request gets executed successfully but 2nd request gets failed with optimistic lock exception:

> javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-5006] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.OptimisticLockException Exception
>   Description: The object cannot be updated because it has changed or
>   been deleted since it was last read.

I have tried putting the updated code in synchronized block but it didn't worked.

I have also tried declaring that rest method synchronized but didn't work.

Now I want my method to be executed by first request and want second request to wait until first request completes it execution.

I had achieved this using `static` variable but don't want to use `static` variable due to code standards.

Can someone give efficient solution for this?

Comment: Executing the database operations within a synchronized block should work, as long as you synchronize on the same instance. Provide more detail about what you used as a lock and how you used it.

Comment: What Persistence tells you is that your second update had a race with first update (which is true according to your question). As a result, whichever update arrived second into internal persistence's syncronized block, did not see the first update, and since updated entity for both of them is the same, second update is rejected, because its data was "stale". What you ideally is supposed to do in this case is purge stale request and reinit it with updated entity, then try to update again.

Comment: Do you have `@Version`  field inside your mapped class with corresponding table column?

Comment: @eg04lt3r - I have version column in my table, which gets updated after every single update.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes , you are right , I am trying to update with stale object therefore getting error, but can you suggest an approach to do that efficiently.

Comment: I don't know of a way that would be considered "efficient" there, especially if data integrity is a concern (and usually it is). Depending on what your entity is, I suppose, you could compare and merge second update onto the entity manually, as part of recovery from the lock exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using synchronization before DB call will help.

1)using Synchronized keyword

```
synchronized(this){
//process
}
```

2)other option is to use synchronized before method name

```
synchronized void <method(){
//process
}
```